# SonarCloud doesn't recognize the aggregated JaCoCo coverage report for multi-module gardle project

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, multi-module, sonarcloud

have multi-module gradle project and using sonarcloud for analyses.
use jacoco-report-aggregation for collecting report across all modules but seems sonarcloud coud't recongize it.

The structire of project
project A

```
ProjectA
  module1
  module2
  module3 - with tests across all modules and aggregated report
```

module1 - build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'jacoco'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED"
    }
   finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jacoco {
   toolVersion = "0.8.10"
   reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/jacoco')
}
jacocoTestReport {
   dependsOn test
   reports {
      xml.required = true
   }
}
```

module2 - build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'jacoco'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED"
    }
   finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jacoco {
   toolVersion = "0.8.10"
   reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/jacoco')
}
jacocoTestReport {
   dependsOn test
   reports {
      xml.required = true
   }
}
```

module3 - build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'jacoco'
   id 'jacoco-report-aggregation'
   id "org.sonarqube" version "4.0.0.2929"
}
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/reports/jacoco/testCodeCoverageReport/testCodeCoverageReport.xml"
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED"
    }
   finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jacoco {
   toolVersion = "0.8.10"
   reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/jacoco')
}
jacocoTestReport {
   dependsOn test
   reports {
      xml.required = true
   }
}
reporting {
    reports {
        testCodeCoverageReport(JacocoCoverageReport) {
            testType = TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST
        }
    }
}
tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn tasks.named('testCodeCoverageReport', JacocoReport)
}
```

after build aggregated coverage report successfully generated by pass

```
module3->build->reports->jacoco->testCodeCoverageReport->testCodeCoverageReport.xml
```

but sonarcloud reported that there is no any report.

Comment: I would try using `layout.buildDirectory.dir('reports/jacoco')` in the sonarqube property as well, to generate the correct path. I'm guessing you have a relative path  starting point issue.